# What kind of pepper is this? Can't identify

Tags: peppers

I'm having trouble identifying my pepper plant, unfortunately I didn't mark it when I was sprouting them. Here are some pictures. Purple-green stems, even in the leaves. Pepper pointing up yellow from day 0. White flowers. A ton of them in a brunch.
Thanks

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Answer (score 1):

Peppers pointing upward are often ornamental or chili peppers.

Just a guess: [Hungarian Yellow Wax Pepper](https://extremehotpeppers.blogspot.com/2012/02/hungarian-yellow-wax.html)

It is rated to 5000-10000 Scoville heat units, so be careful when you taste it.